# How do I redirect back to the same tab after submitting a form?

Tags: forms

I'm creating a custom tab for events. I've used hook_civicrm_tabset to add a tab to the event management pages. In that tab, I have a form generated using civix. Upon saving the form, my operations are successfully completed and I'm redirected back to the event management "Info and Settings" tab. I would like to end up back on the same tab instead.

How do I end up back in my custom tab after submitting my form?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

When creating the array for the tab, add "ajaxForm" to the "class" index.

```
$newTab = array(
  'title' => 'New Tab',
  'link' => 'url',
  'class' => 'ajaxForm', //<---- The important part
  //etc
);
```